# Python: Upload a photo to photobucket

Tags: python, photobucket

Can a Python script upload a photo to photo bucket and then retrieve the URL for it? Is so how?

I found a script at this link: http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=240x677

But I just found that confusing.

many thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. Photobucket has a well-documented [API](http://photobucket.com/developer/documentation), and someone wrote a [wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/photobucket-api-py/) around it.

Download the it and put it into your Python path, then download httplib2 (you can use easy_install or pip for this one).

Then, you have to request a key for the [Photobucket API](http://photobucket.com/developer/documentation).

If you did everything right, you can write your script now. The Python wrapper is great, but is not documented at all which makes it very difficult to use it. I spent hours on understanding it (compare the question and response time here). As example, the script even has form/multipart support, but I had to read the code to find out how to use it. I had to prefix the filename with a `@`.

This library is a great example how you should NOT document your code!

I finally got it working, enjoy the script: (it even has oAuth handling!)

```
import pbapi

import webbrowser
import cPickle
import os
import re
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree

__author__ = "leoluk"

###############################################
##               CONFIGURATION               ##
###############################################

# File in which the oAuth token will be stored
TOKEN_FILE = "token.txt"

IMAGE_PATH = r"D:\Eigene Dateien\Bilder\SC\foo.png"

IMAGE_RECORD = {
    "type": 'image',
    "uploadfile": '@'+IMAGE_PATH,

    "title": "My title", # <---
    "description": "My description", # <---
}

ALBUM_NAME = None # default album if None


API_KEY = "149[..]"
API_SECRET = "528[...]"


###############################################
##                   SCRIPT                  ##
###############################################

api = pbapi.PbApi(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

api.pb_request.connection.cache = None

# Test if service online
api.reset().ping().post()

result = api.reset().ping().post().response_string

ET = ElementTree.fromstring(result)

if ET.find('status').text != 'OK':
    sys.stderr.write("error: Ping failed \n"+result)
    sys.exit(-1)

try:
    # If there is already a saved oAuth token, no need for a new one
    api.username, api.pb_request.oauth_token = cPickle.load(open(TOKEN_FILE))
except (ValueError, KeyError, IOError, TypeError):
    # If error, there's no valid oAuth token

    # Getting request token
    api.reset().login().request().post().load_token_from_response()

    # Requesting user permission (you have to login with your account)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(api.login_url)

    raw_input("Press Enter when you finished access permission. ")

    #Getting oAuth token
    api.reset().login().access().post().load_token_from_response()


# This is needed for getting the right subdomain
infos = api.reset().album(api.username).url().get().response_string

ET = ElementTree.fromstring(infos)

if ET.find('status').text != 'OK':
    # Remove the invalid oAuth
    os.remove(TOKEN_FILE)
    # This happend is user deletes the oAuth permission online
    sys.stderr.write("error: Permission deleted. Please re-run.")
    sys.exit(-1)

# Fresh values for username and subdomain
api.username = ET.find('content/username').text
api.set_subdomain(ET.find('content/subdomain/api').text)

# Default album name
if not ALBUM_NAME:
    ALBUM_NAME = api.username

# Debug :-)
print "User: %s" % api.username

# Save the new, valid oAuth token
cPickle.dump((api.username, api.oauth_token), open(TOKEN_FILE, 'w'))

# Posting the image
result = (api.reset().album(ALBUM_NAME).
          upload(IMAGE_RECORD).post().response_string)

ET = ElementTree.fromstring(result)

if ET.find('status').text != 'OK':
    sys.stderr.write("error: File upload failed \n"+result)
    sys.exit(-1)


# Now, as an example what you could do now, open the image in the browser

webbrowser.open_new_tab(ET.find('content/browseurl').text)
```

Comment: Hey, thx for the answer just got one little problem. I cant import pbapi i get the "no module named pbapi". I copied the files http://photobucket-api-py.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PbApi/pbapi/   in this folder and appended my python path to this folder. Is that the correct way of installing pbapi?

Comment: Better is to copy the folders pbapi and oauth to C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\

Comment: ah, im on Fedora not windows my bad

Comment: /usr/lib/pythonXX/site-packages/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [python API by Ron White](http://code.google.com/p/photobucket-api-py/) that was written to do just this

Comment: It is the worst API wrapper I've ever seen, but I finally got it working, see my response.

Comment: sorry, didnt write it myself, but glad it helped. it probably would have taken more than the 5 hours you spent debugging it to write your own. consider including your comments or a link to this ticket to the owners

Comment: Once you understand it, it's great, but there's no help at all and so it's pretty frustrating to use it.